# show dbs command is not working in windows CMD

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongo DB in my windows machine and even set the path in the environmental variables

when I type mongo I got the following output

[image]

when I type mongod I got the following output

[image]

And for some reason show DBS does not work in the cmd

[image]

is there any way I can solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your images are not very clear to see what is in the image. Also, mention the MongoDB and the OS versiions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing  `show dbs` in Windows command line and on a nfs location.

You have to execute the query in mongo shell. Open mongo shell and execute `show dbs`

Mongo shell is different and mongo server is different. In your first image you started mongo daemon using `mongod`. It starts a server in the default port 27017.

In the this image, you are executing the command which is not mongo shell.

To start mongo shell and other options, [Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo)

Comment: Yep I got it, Thanks for the help